# Making a shape act like a connector and snap to another shape. Visio

Tags: shapes, visio, stencils

I'm pretty new to Visio but I'm trying to figure how I could possible design a stencil to snap to a connector marker on another stencil/shape.

I have looked into actually editing the connector itself too see how its designed. I'm wondering If I could recreate the Endpoint on a single location for a shape stencil. Which would snap into place on to the designated shape, when a user drags it on to the worksheet.

[image: Example 1]

Would anyone have any ideas or pointers on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Connector is "thing in itself"! How it works only the original developers of visio (in the era before MS) knew...

Comment: I think you just need a connection point on the shape.

Comment: @PaulHerber, Maybe I didn't explain it too well but I was wanted to create a shape that acts like a connector to attach to a location on another shape. I figured it out and will be sharing the resource I used!

Comment: Look at making a shape 1D rather than 2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here.

http://visiozone.com/?p=298

Pretty much I had to take a 1D shape (A line) and Adjust the parameters of its boundary box inside the master shape, then group it too get it to act like a 2d shape. After, I could edit the group and add the shape I wanted then. Deleting the line and adjusting the endpoints.

Highly recommend checking the link out. I hope this helps anyone out there with this issue.

I'm not sure why its really difficult to find information on Visio. Being a 19 year old program. Haha.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, and I don't understand why to start from a line in the first place. Why not start from the 2D shape and then switch the behavior to 1D which is what you need to do anyway after grouping the line. However, when switching the shape behavior to 1D it still doesn't act as a line connector, anymore. Instead, moving the endpoint simply changes the length of the shape. I'm using Visio 2302.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments and your self-given answer I gather that you actually want to glue a 2-D shape to another 2-D shape. The simplest way to do this is to use outward connection points as described in the "Make a connection point inward, outward, or both" section at the bottom of the [Edit connector lines, arrows, or points](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/edit-connector-lines-arrows-or-points-5669491f-9fce-4676-81f8-ef4553788416) Visio support page:

> Use inward and outward connection points to control how to attract connector endpoints on shapes.
>
> 1. Select the shape.
> 2. On the Home tab, in the Tools group, click the Connection Point tool Button image.
> 3. If connection points are not visible, on the View tab, in the Visual Aids group, select the Connection Points check box.
> 4. If you want an outward or inward & outward connection point, right-click the connection point and click:
>
>    - Inward [...]
>    - Outward - If you have a 2-D shape that you want to glue to another shape, you want an outward connection point. An outward connection point is attracted to inward connection points.
>    - Inward & Outward [...]